# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed - LifestylePerWcfOperation

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I have a WCF Web Service that is currently encountering some concurrency issues. The load is small at the moment, but is expected to increase a great amount in the next few days.

The overall setup is WCF, Entity Framework 6, Dependency Injection (Castle Windsor), UnitOfWork & Repository Pattern.

I setup a stress test that hits the service in parallel and I can recreate concurrency errors such as....

- An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server.
- The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.
- The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

From the research I've done, it looks like I should injecting my DbContext with a LifestylePerWcfOperation. Currently it's being done with LifestyleTransient.

When I switch over to LifestylePerWcfOperation and rerun the test, I get this every time:

- The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

So I really have 2 questions:

1. Am I correct in the assumption the true solution to this is switching my DbContext to LifestylePerWcfOperation?
2. If so, is it apparent why my DbContext is getting gobbled up?

Here's some code:

AppStart.cs:

```
IocContainer.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

IocContainer.Register(Component.For<IRepositoryFactory>().AsFactory());

IocContainer.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
                               .ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>)
                             /*.LifestylePerWcfOperation()*/);

IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IDbContext))
                               .ImplementedBy(dbContextType)
                               .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", String.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["---"].ConnectionString))));
                             /*.LifestylePerWcfOperation()*/

IocContainer.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
                               .ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>))
                               .LifestyleTransient()
                             /*.LifestylePerWcfOperation()*/);

// Register the actual dbContextType so consuming applications can access it without an interface
IocContainer.Register(Component.For(dbContextType)
                               .Named(dbContextType.Name)
                               .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", String.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["----"].ConnectionString)));
                             /*.LifestylePerWcfOperation()*/
```

UnitOfWork.cs:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;
    private bool _disposed;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public Repository(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbset = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        return _dbset.AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbset.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(ICollection<T> entities)
    {
        entities.ToList().ForEach(Delete);
    }
}
```

I can add more code if needed. Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Your DBContext registration does not specify a lifestyle, so Windsor's default will apply: Singleton. This will definitely cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1) You are correct in changing the lifestyle to LifestylePerWcfOperation

2) You are disposing the DBContext from within the UnitOfWork. DBContext is injected by Windsor, hence Windsor will call Dispose on it. When using windsor never dispose injected objects, only if you created an object using a factory or Resolve you have to Release (not dispose) the object, so Windsor can dispose it.

I would expect that with the LifeStylePerWcfOperations and removing the Dispose code, the code should run fine.

Good luck,
Marwijn.

Comment: Thanks Marwijn! This was indeed the first step. There were some other changes I needed to make in code that wasn't posted here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved.

Fix was exactly what Marwijn mentioned. After fixing that, I still got a similar error.

The final fix was to take every single registration and make it LifestylePerWcfOperation. I had some objects registered with a shorter lifetime, and so DbContext was also getting disposed with those objects.

If anyone gets this error, and you're using Castle / EF, don't explicitly dispose DbContext (let Castle do it) and make everything LifestylePerWcfOperation. That should fix it. Then go back and selectively reset the lifestyle of any objects you don't want to be LifestylePerWcfOperation and make sure it doesn't break as you go.